# How are the "featured" matches to spectate chosen?

Tags: league-of-legends

With the new Spectator Patch for *League of Legends*, spectating normal and ranked games is now possible.  You can either watch a game your friends are in or there are also 5 "featured" games going on at the home screen.  Are these just random ranked games?  Those at the top of the ladder?  If the former, is there a way to watch the high level "masters" games?

Comment: I can't comment on whether they're completely random, but I haven't seen any players below 1600 Elo in the featured games. I'm inclined to say it's those at the top of the ladder.

Comment: Can't find any notes on this, but I've seen only arranged 5v5 ranked games. Only teams.

Comment: Normal games can appear as well. And not just 5v5 ranked games. Duo ranked games, and even games involving one person versus a bot. That only happens if few people are playing, however, so your best time of catching that would be immediately after a patch.

Answer (score 3):

From the Darius patch notes:

> Improved the algorithm for selecting Featured Games to include more Normal and Ranked Team games with extremely skilled players <sup>[1](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2141119)</sup>

Spectator Mode tends to pick skilled and slightly-above-average players. After this patch, it will choose exceptional players more often. Normal, Ranked, and even Bot games can be featured, though.

From personal experience, it seems like the five featured games are arranged according to Elo. From left to right, the best players will generally be in the first game, and gradually decrease in skill as you scroll to the last featured game.

Comment: I just saw the patch and came to update that question. Too late :P +1 for you

Comment: I thought someone else might have the same idea, haha. Thanks!